# Copy Constructor, Assignment operator overloading

Tags: c++, object, instance, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Unit now I've never needed to overload the assignment parameter or write a Copy Constructor 
(at least, it seems I never had to, because I never had problems)

as far as I know the Assignment Operator must be overloaded when I want to copy a Object and its values to another Object after initialization (Same of CopyConstructor, but when its initialized).

```
Object a;
Object b;

// do something with a
b = a; //for this line, the Assignment Parameter must be overloaded (nearly never do such things)
Object c = a; // needs a Copy constructor
```

But If I would write it like this:

```
Object a;
Object* b;

b = &a; //I think I won't need one here since b actually points to Object a
Object* c = a; // I think same here
```

But what should I do, if I copy a object outside of its own class/parent class.

```
class MyOtherClass{Object obj..........}

void MyOtherClass::SetObject(Object obj)
{
  this->obj = obj; // Assignment operator overloading needed in class Object?
}
```

do I have to overload the Assignment Operator in the Object class?
What if I do following:

```
void MyOtherClass::SetObject(Object &obj)
{
  this->obj = obj; // Assignment operator overloading needed in class Object?
}
```

And the final question, does this also include `Enums`?(I think yes)

```
void MyOtherClass::SetObject(ENumClass Eobj)
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

For the question of whether or not to implement an assignment operator, the answer is - it depends.

Remember that the compiler will generate its own default assignment operator if you do not provide one yourself (and in C++11, if you do not explicitly disable the default operator).  The default operator performs an assignment of each individual class member using their own assignment operators.

So as long as your class members are assignment-safe in their own right, then the default operator is sufficient and you do not need to provide your own operator.  You only need to provide your own operator when you need to perform custom actions, like deep-copying dynamically allocated members, debug logging, input validation, etc.

Comment: so for my Setter method I don't need to overload it?

Answer (score 0):

It is legal to write an assignment operator that assigns from a base type and it is also legal to write an assignment operator that assigns from a concrete object of the same type. However, even though both are legal, it is generally better design to implement assignment from an object of the same type or from other concrete types for which such an assignment actually makes sense and not from a general type.

That being said, it does vary from application to application. To be a little more specific, consider:

```
                     Shape
        /             |                \
      Triangle      Quadrilateral      Circle
```

... it probably would not make sense to have an assignment operator in Circle that could assign from any Shape. What would that method even do? These different implementations have nothing  in common.

Now, alternatively, consider:

```
                     Point2D
                     /     \
          CartesianCoord   PolarCoord
```

... in an application like this, it might make sense to provide an assignment operator that accepts a general Point2D in order to facilitate conversions between the two types. In this case, all implementations represent the same information and can be converted non-destructively between representations. As a result, allowing a more general conversion would make sense in this context.

So, really, it's all about what makes sense conceptually. If you can assign to/from an object in a way that does not destroy information, it is sane; if your assignment is destructive, it's likely a poor design.

As for the parameters, one typically uses "const T&" (where "T" is the type from which you are assigning) or "T&&" in the case of destructive assignment. The return type of the assignment should be a reference to an object of the same type as the current object. In other words:

```
class CartesianCoord : public Point2D {
 public:
   // ...
   CartesianCoord& operator=(const Point2D&);
};
```

Or

```
class CartesianCoord : public Point2D {
 public:
   // ...
   CartesianCoord& operator=(const Point2D&);
   CartesianCoord& operator=(CartesianCoord&&); // fast destructive assignment
};
```

Or

```
class CartesianCoord : public Point2D {
 public:
   // ...
   CartesianCoord& operator=(const CartesianCoord&);  // if conversion disallowed
   CartesianCoord& operator=(CartesianCoord&&); // fast destructive assignment
};
```

Comment: What is a concrete object? And why all the talk of inheritance?

Comment: A concrete object is an object with all of its methods implemented (no pure virtual methods). The talk of inheritance is because it seemed that the question was asking about what the parameter to the assignment operator should be in the case of inheritance.

Comment: Can you have a non-concrete object?

Comment: You cannot instantiate a non-concrete object, but when it comes to declarations and types, yes, you can have a non-concrete object.

Comment: No, an object is an instance. You cannot have a non-concrete object.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to be redundant here. Especially when there are very generic types like "Object" as a general base class in other programming languages. Practical communication is more important than formal terminological precision.

Comment: informative answer, but I actually just need to know if I have to overload the assignment when I'm using something like a Setter Method which copies the object

Comment: @Sleicreider. It's unclear what you are asking. Or where the source of confusion is. You can just invoke your setter method from operator=() assuming you need both a setter method and operator=() (though it's unclear why you need both and can't simply rename your setter functions to operator=).

Comment: You are not being redundant. You are mixing up established terminology, leading to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a separate method SetObject() which duplicates operator=() semantic?

So that correctly assign a base class to derived you can overload operator=() in the derived object this way

```
DerivedObj& DerivedObj::operator=(const BaseObj& rhs){
    // call parent operator= in functional form
    BaseObj::operator=(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

Of course you should implement

```
BaseObj& BaseObj::operator=(const BaseObj& rhs)
```

However if you need assign base class to derived I would not say it's a good design

Comment: Why do you use a separate method SetObject() which duplicates operator=() semantic? What do you mean with this sentence?

Actually I don't want to assign a base class to a derived.
MyOtherClass should just have a setter method to get the Object obj.

Example: 

`int main()
{
   Object obj;
    //do things with obh
   MyOtherClass other;
   other.SetObject(obj);
}` //Somehow the `code` format looks terrible here, sorry!

Comment: I don't think it's "of course". BaseObj::operator=(const BaseObj&) may not always make sense. In general, I would omit operator=() from base classes. (In a good design, base classes have no state, anyway, so such an assignment operator wouldn't do anything, anyway, and as far as an API is concerned, promising assignment at the base class level is a recipe for disaster).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Agree, but in general base class for the target object (which we implement operator=() for) could be derived for something else (and could have state, public methods etc)

Comment: One would hope that an implementation class that provides implementation, not just interface, would be reused through composition, not further inheritance.

Comment: @Sleicreider Do you mean SetObject(obj) reset a state of your class? If so you can construct new MyOtherClass from Object and swap it with your object.